# Opencarts $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts() returns wrong/nonexistant date_modified

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, foreach, opencart

I'm making an Atom feeder for Opencart that seems to work great on a stock 1.5.6x dev store. However when I migrate it into a live store (and dev) the `_product` table `date_modified` column always returns `getProduct()` result array with either `2015-01-15 10:45:18` or `2014-12-01 12:52:23` for each `$result['date_modified']` in product row....in a seemingly random fashion.

Some things I tried:

- Checked the `getProduct()` function instead to make sure it pulls the correct `date_modified`.
- Checked to make sure `date_modified` is actually `DATETIME` column and is not returning a string instead.
- I have cleaned the DB of rogue/nomad rows and checked/repaired for any crashes.
- I have tried returning the `date_modified` without using any formatting such as `date(DATE_ATOM, $time)`
- I have turned off all other mods that affect the `getProducts()` function. There is no difference in code between stock and live `getProducts()`.
- I have reconstructed the DB connect outside of OC and pulled the `date_modified` successfully without any `LEFT JOIN` tables into the schema.
- I have located those dates in the `manufacturer` table but there doesn't seem to be any corrupt data, the column is set to `DATETIME` and `JOIN`s are functioning properly.
- I have pulled most of my hair out for 2 days searching for how a column or this query could corrupt out like this without triggering any errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After posting this I noticed that the live store has a `date_modified` on the manufacturer table (and others). Additionally, OC stores literal apostrophes which were messing up some queries as well as JSON for those entities.

The extra `date_modified` on manufacturer table apparently came from a modified OC install called "OpenShop". We didn't realize that there is an included `.sql` script that executed during the install process. So the queries using `JOIN` were pulling the manufacturer `date_modified` instead of the products.

The solution is to add `p.date_modified,` after the `SELECT` statements in `getProduct()` and `getProducts()` (or any other `JOIN` queries where you want to explicitly pull the correct modified). Another solution is to delete those 3rd party `date_modified` columns, but they are kinda handy.

In addition, be careful with the apostrophes in names of manufacturer, option, etc. We ended up removing them for now and will code better storage procedures later on.